# Create xmlns with prefix using XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml, dom

I would like to create a `dom` with the following structure.

```
<CreateImport xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <XmlData>
  ...other child nodes
  </XmlData>
</CreateImport>
```

I know how to create an `XmlElement` with a normal namespace like

```
<CreateImport xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

But now my `xmlns` has a prefix `i` and I want to add that programmatically to my `XmlDocument`.
I got confused over `XElement` vs `XmlElement`. The former cannot have a child of type `XmlElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XDocument`, `XElement` and so on are used in Linq To XML. But they can also be used to create XML documents in an easier way as with `XmlDocument` in my opinion. In your case you can write something like this:

```
XElement root = new XElement("CreateImport", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                             new XElement("XmlData", 
                                          new XElement("Child1"), 
                                          new XElement("Child2")));
```

You can use `root.Save("myxml.xml")` to save this to a file. This will create following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CreateImport xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   Content
</CreateImport>
```

You can read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb387098.aspx for more details and examples.

Comment: OK thanks. but how can I add the `XmlData` element as a child? I'm not going to save this documents anywhere. I have to send it to a web service as a string.

Comment: I've edited my answer. But please see the enclosed link for further details. And please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.